# C: How to make "pointer return function"'s argument NULL safe?

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

So, I am coding uppercase function with using pointers. I am trying to make a ERROR message when there is input but unfortunately in terminal I am seeing nothing like s==NULL is not working very well I cant see any ERROR messages.

Probably problem about argument types and pointer but I don't real seeing it!

If my Program Arguments like this:

```
"Hello 123dsd" "teSting"
```

Output is:

```
HELLO 123DSD

TESTING
```

If my program arguments is blank:

output is nothing:

I want to show ERROR message if arguments are empty like:

```
Please insert a string!
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAGIC_NUMBER 32

char *uppercase(char *s)
{
    if (s == NULL)
    {
        printf("Please insert a string!");
        return 0; //Not working!!
    }
    else
    {
        for(char *p = s; *p!=0; ++p)
        {
            if ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z')
                *p = *p - MAGIC_NUMBER;
        }

        return s;
    }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    for(int i=1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", uppercase(argv[i]));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: With `*s == NULL`, you are dereferencing `s`, so it returns the value of the first character of the array. So, you want to check the pointer _value_ and you want `s == NULL` (without the `*`)

Comment: What exactly means "is not working very well" or "Not working!!". `argv[i]` with `i<argc` should never be a `NULL` pointer. Although some implementations of `printf` will print `(null)` when you pass a `NULL` pointer, this is undefined behavior. You should check the return value of a function that may return `NULL` and pass it to `printf` only if it is not `NULL`.

Comment: @Bodo Can you able to show with code I would be so happy thank you so much for your time!

Comment: Instead of `MAGIC_NUMBER`, you could make it a little less magic by writing it `'a' - 'A'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell I can't #define like that result is messing up it giving me @ instead of uppercase letters

Comment: @Bobamas First, apply the suggestion in Craig Estey's comment. Then, please, [edit] your question and show the command line you use to run your program, the actual output and the expected output. Or describe what you want to achieve. Without this it is not clear how to modify the code to fulfill your needs. What exactly do you want me to show? How to avoid passing a `NULL` pointer to `printf`?

Comment: @Bobamas `#define MAGIC_NUMBER ('a' - 'A')` should work without problems. In your case it should work even without parentheses, but I recommend to keep the parentheses.

Comment: @Bodo Thank you so much I edit my question I hope it is much more clear ?

Comment: @Bobamas I intentionally added a program name `myprogram` to the command line to make it more clear to the reader that it is a command line and not some other type of input. Of course I don't assume that your program is actually called `myprogram`, but the name doesn't really matter for the example in the question.

Comment: Thank you so much @Bodo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call your program without arguments, it doesn't print anything because the loop will not call `printf` or `uppercase` since `argc` will have the value `1`.

You have to add code to `main` to handle this case.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if(argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Please insert a string!\n")
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i=1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", uppercase(argv[i]));
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Note that I use `fprintf(stderr, ...)` for the error message because error messages should not be mixed with normal output.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't enter any parameters to the program, `argc` will be 1 so the `for` loop in the `main` function is never entered.  This also means that a NULL pointer will never be passed to `uppercase`.

You need to move the check for missing arguments to `main`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Please insert a string!");
        return 1;
    }
    for(int i=1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n", uppercase(argv[i]));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was struggling with this arguments over an hour!